# Cannot figure out how to get \graphicspath to work

Tags: graphics

I am trying to include the exact path name in `\graphicspath` where my images are located. Unfortunately some of the directories have spaces in them, but I am bypassing this with the "`~1`" trick in the path name, ex., `/my_pro~1`. I have read multiple help questions regarding this matter but cannot figure it out.

Please help. I am fit to be tied here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As `~` is a special char to LaTeX it may lead to unwanted behavior. It would be very good if you could post an example what you actually pass to `\graphicspath`.

Comment: Welcome, rule of thumb for any new user to a computer: Do not use spaces or non-acii characters iin file and directory names.

Comment: I got rid of the spaces but the problem still exists. I have _ and - characters in the pathname now. Is this the problem?

Comment: Use the `grffile` package to allow spaces in your paths.

Comment: Where exactly are the files? Are they in a subdir to the dir with your tex file in it? Or somewhere outside it. If the later case your probably better off specifying the full path not any tilde shortcuts.

Comment: I finally fixed it. I removed every space from the pathname, replacing it with an underscore, and I placed a backslash at the very end of the pathname.

Thanks for the help, everyone.